# How to GROUP and AVG rows using LIKE

Tags: sql, group-by, average, sql-like

I am using Crystal Reports v10.  My current result set looks like this (there are 44 rows, this is an example):

```
item code     item desc          cost
21010DF       DOUG FIR 2x10-10   300.00
21012DF       DOUG FIR 2x10-12   310.50
21014DF       DOUG FIR 2x10-14   313.25
21016DF       DOUG FIR 2x10-16   316.10
21018DF       DOUG FIR 2x10-18   319.56
2410DF        DOUG FIR 2x4-10    271.69
2412DF        DOUG FIR 2x4-12    273.12
2414DF        DOUG FIR 2x4-14    275.98
12CDX         PLYWOOD 1/2 CDX     15.00
34TGADV       PLYWOOD T&G ADV     24.00
58CDX         PLYWOOD 5/8 CDX     18.00
```

I've been asked to group these items and provide an average cost for each group.  The grouping rules are defined by the organization (they are random - some are logically groups while some rows are left out of of the logical group).

The result set needs to look like this:

```
item desc                 avg cost
DOUG FIR 2x10 (10-14)     300.00
DOUG FIR 2x10-16          316.10
DOUG FIR 2x10-18          319.56
DOUG FIR 2x4 (10-14)      271.69
PLYWOOD CDX                16.50    
PLYWOOD T&G ADV            24.00
```

So far, this is what I got but it doesn't seem to be coming close to what I need:

```
SELECT item_cd, item.item_desc, AVG(inv.cst) as avg cost
FROM item, inv
WHERE item.item_id = inv.item_id
AND item.item_cd LIKE '210%DF'
GROUP BY item.item_cd, item.item_desc
```

Can anyone provide advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: If the groups your user wants has specific rules, why dont you create a field with "groupnumber", update aplying such rules and then group by such field?

Comment: This is a **really** bad way to store your data.  Try to restructure the database so that you have, for example, `wood_type` (with values of `DOUG FIR`, `PLYWOOD`, etc), and `dimensions` (with values of `2x10`, `2x10`, etc), and then the third value after the hyphen (I don't really know what that represents, but make a column for it).

Comment: Jack Maney - this would be a great suggestion if I were able to modify the db but, unfortunately, I can't. Any other suggestions?

Comment: jclozano - Could you provide me with more info/sql? Your comments sound interesting but my SQL knowledge is too limited to fully understand.

Comment: @Piet - Then get whoever can restructure the data to do so.  It's a mess.  That said, if your RDBMS allows for regular expressions, you should be able to grab the pieces of the `item_desc` column that you need.  If it doesn't...well, you might want to yank the data outside of a database and use a scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if there is no logic to the grouping, then it has to be manual, sorry. In your case, for that particular result set, you can do the following:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN item_cd IN ('21010DF','21012DF','21014DF') THEN 'DOUG FIR 2x10 (10-14)'
        WHEN item_cd IN ('2410DF','2412DF','2414DF') THEN 'DOUG FIR 2x4 (10-14)'
        WHEN item_cd IN ('12CDX','58CDX') THEN 'PLYWOOD CDX' ELSE item.item_desc END item_desc,
        AVG(inv.cst) as avg cost
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN inv
ON item.item_id = inv.item_id
WHERE item.item_cd LIKE '210%DF'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN item_cd IN ('21010DF','21012DF','21014DF') THEN 'DOUG FIR 2x10 (10-14)'
         WHEN item_cd IN ('2410DF','2412DF','2414DF') THEN 'DOUG FIR 2x4 (10-14)'
         WHEN item_cd IN ('12CDX','58CDX') THEN 'PLYWOOD CDX' ELSE item.item_desc END
```

But you should do what @jclozano said in a comment, and have the items that need to be grouped on a column marking that they belong to that specific group.

Comment: Lamak...I'll give this a shot.  But, to my previous comment regarding @jclozano remark, what is meant by "have the items that need to be grouped on a column marking that they belong to that specific group."

Comment: @Piet: What Lamak and jclozano possibly mean is, you need a `Categories` (or, if you like, `ReportingCategories`) table that would contain all the group descriptions, and your `Items` table (or whatever it is called) would reference that category table. The items should be categorised *before* running the report. That way you would be able to group the items based on their respective categories and to use the category names as descriptions in your query. Of course, we cannot know much about the entire design and whether it is possible to separate this categorisation process from the reporting.